# Use collapse like summarize

Tags: stata, reshape, data-manipulation

I want to use Stata's `collapse` like `summarize`.  Say I have data (the 1's correspond to the same person, so do the 2's and the 3's) that, when `summarize`d, looks like this:

```
        Obs    Mean    Std. Dev.    Min    Max
Score1    54     17          3        11    22
Score2    32     13          2        5     28
Score3    43     22          4        17    33 
Value1    54     9           3        2     12
Value2    32     31          7        22    44 
Value3    43     38          4        31    45
Speed1    54     3           1        1     11 
Speed2    32     6           3        2     12 
Speed3    43     8           2        2     15
```

How would I create a new dataset (using `collapse` or something else) that looks somewhat like what `summarize` gives, but looks like the following?  Note that the numbers after the variables correspond to observations in my data.  So `Score1`, `Value1`, and `Speed1` all correspond to _n==1.

```
_n  ScoreMean   ValueMean   SpeedMean ScoreMax ValueMax SpeedMax
1     17          9           3       22       12       11
2     13          31          6       28       44       12
3     22          38          8       33       45       15
```

(I have omitted Std. Dev. and Min for brevity.)

When I run `collapse (mean) Score1 Score2 Score3 Value1 Value2 Value3 Speed1 Speed2 Speed3`, I get the following, which is not very helpful:

```
     Score1  Score2  Score3  Value1  Value2  Value3  Speed1  Speed2  Speed3
1    17      13      22      9       31      38      3       6       8
```

This is on the right track.  It only gives me the mean, though.  I am not sure how to have it give me more than one statistic at once.  I think I need to somehow use `reshape` at some point.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This starts with Roberto's example toy dataset. I think it generalises more easily to 800 objects. (By the way, in Stata `_n` always and only means observation number in current dataset or group defined by `by:`, so your usage is mild abuse of syntax.)

```
clear 
input score1 score2 value1 value2 speed1 speed2
5 8 346 235 80 89
2 10 642 973 65 78
end

gen j = _n
reshape long score value speed, i(j) j(i)
rename score yscore
rename value yvalue
rename speed yspeed
reshape long y, i(i j) j(what) string
collapse (mean) mean=y (min) min=y (max) max=y, by(what i)
reshape wide mean min max, j(what) i(i) string
```

Answer (score 3):

One way, following your lead:

```
*clear all
set more off

input ///
score1 score2 value1 value2 speed1 speed2
5 8 346 235 80 89
2 10 642 973 65 78
end

list

summarize

*-----

collapse (mean) score1m=score1 score2m=score2 ///
    value1m=value1 value2m=value2 ///
    speed1m=speed1 speed2m=speed2 ///
    (max) score1max=score1 score2max=score2 ///
    value1max=value1 value2max=value2 ///
    speed1max=speed1 speed2max=speed2

gen obs = _n

reshape long score@m score@max value@m value@max speed@m speed@max, i(obs) j(n)
drop obs

list
```

Asking for several statistics is easy. Use the `[(stat)] target_var=varname` syntax so you don't get conflicting names when asking for several statistics. Then, `reshape`.

If there are many variables/subjects, it will turn very tedious. There are other ways. I will revise the answer later if no one posts an alternative by then.

Comment: Wow - thank you so much.  This works perfectly!

As far as there being lots of variables - there are 800, so I will have _n from 1 to 800.